# Apply a TableStyle to a Word Table

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, docx

Trying to style a table using a predefined style but nothing is working. I've tried with a a newly created document and one created from a saved template. Using the SDK Productivity tool I can see the style is there in the template but it's not being applied. I've tried appended the style or setting it directly and neither seem to work.

```
    public static void CreateWordprocessingDocument(string fileName) {

        string[,] data = {
            {"Texas", "TX"},
            {"California", "CA"},
            {"New York", "NY"},
            {"Massachusetts", "MA"}
        };

        using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true)) {

            // We need to change the file type from template to document.
            wordDocument.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

            var body = wordDocument.GetDocument().Body;

            Table table = new Table();

            TableProperties props = new TableProperties();
            TableStyle tableStyle = new TableStyle { Val = "Light Shading Accent 1" };
            props.TableStyle = tableStyle;
            //props.Append(tableStyle);
            table.AppendChild(props);

            for (var i = 0; i <= data.GetUpperBound(0); i++) {
                var tr = new TableRow();
                for (var j = 0; j <= data.GetUpperBound(1); j++) {
                    var tc = new TableCell();
                    tc.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(data[i, j]))));
                    tc.Append(new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Auto }));
                    tr.Append(tc);
                }
                table.Append(tr);
            }
            body.Append(table);
            wordDocument.GetDocument().Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the exact same code except for this line. Not sure if that would make a difference. table.AppendChild<TableProperties>( tPr );

Comment: The cast should not make a difference (just tested to confirm). Are your tables appearing styled?

Comment: Yes, they do. I can apply the style manually to the table too.

Comment: I can apply most of the properties (like border, color, etc) manually as well and that works fine. But I creating a lot of tables and would like to be able to use a predefined style to both simplify the code and allow them to be changed easier.

Comment: What do you see in the xml file with the productivity tools? I see something like <w:tbl><w:tblPr><w:tblStyle w:val="MyTableStyle"/>....

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I was using the style name and not the style id. So the line where the style is declared should look like:

```
TableStyle tableStyle = new TableStyle { Val = "LightShading-Accent1" };
```